# What to copy when moving cygwin from one machine to the other?

Tags: windows, cygwin

I'm reinstalling everything on my machine, and amongst those is Cygwin. I'm trying to avoid reinstallation, partly because I don't even know what it is that I've installed. Can I just move the Cygwin directory from one machine to another and expect everything to work, or are there some other important settings that I need to move as well?

As far as I saw, it's pretty self-contained, but one never knows.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yep! Go for it. You won't encounter any problems.

You can just copy the entire cygwin directory to your new machine, open up the cygwin shell and everything (as long as you are only calling cygwin-internal programs and stuff that's within the path) will just work as if you you are working on your old machine.

The only thing you'll loose is the directory where the "already downloaded and compressed" packages for a possible re-installation are stored. Fortunately this directory is optional, so no problem for migration to another platform. You could copy that directory as well, but most likely all the packages that you have are outdated anyways and a run of setup.exe would fetch the new versions anyway...

Btw - since someone said exactly the opposite some real-life experience: I use this feature quite often with success. I've copied my cygwin dir to USB-sticks and used it on friends computers. I also copied it to the laptop of my fiance when we go to holidays and take a laptop with us.

It always worked without **any** problems....

Comment: Well, there goes ... I've just moved it, and at first it seems everything went ok. If I run into problems six months from now, I'm coming to get you :-))) Thanks, Nils!

Comment: Movability is the best argument I've heard for keeping Cygwin in its own dir, instead of root c:\

Comment: Here is a topic expliaining caveats of a move http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2003-10/msg00945.html

Comment: You will lose all file mode when copying on Windows. See my answer for details.

Comment: this is an incorrect answer based on my tests, i copied cygwin dir from xp to a virtualbox with xp and man is not working, only reinstall solve it

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is: No, you can't copy the whole Cygwin folder. You just copy the configuration files(bash files, vim file, etc.) you need.

The long answer is: If you copy the whole Cygwin folder, it may work in some case, and may not in some other case.

The reason is: you will lose linux `file mode` when copying files on Windows. And that will cause a lot of troubles. However, you may not have the troubles when you use Cygwin just like a common Windows Program(which means you don't care file mode and anything related), and run it as Windows Administrator(which is not required when Cygwin is installed as usual).

BTW: you can export the packages you installed by `cygcheck.exe -c` and install them on the new Cygwin. You can also install/update Cygwin packages by Cygwin's `setup-x86_64.exe` in command line like:

```
setup-x86_64.exe -q -P package1,package2,package3
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to reinstall it from the cygwin installer, sorry!

Most importantly you'll want to copy everything from your home directory (default is c:/cygwin/home/) especially anything w/ a "." in front of the filename.

As for individual application preferences, etc., you may lose those -- but if you do the reinstall while you still have access to your old machine -- you can probably get to 90% of your previous install without too much trouble.

Comment: Why can't I copy it ? Do you know, perhaps? It will go to the machine with the same software as the old one.

Answer (score 1):

My experience with copying from one cygwin64 (I don't think there is a difference) to another machine is that all of the symbolic links got crushed:

As an example:

What used to be `/usr/bin/cc -> /usr/bin/gcc.exe` (or something like that)
After the copy /usr/bin/cc became a text file containing the string:

```
!<symlink>/usr/bin/gcc.exe
```

My method of copy was merely `cp -r /cygwin/c/cygwin64 <dest>`

My dest was a FAT32 FS, but I don't think that had anything to do with it.
There were also characters 0x00 and 0xFF sprinkled among many of these 'text' files so that they appeared to be binary.